# Binary Tree Iterator in C++ works for T=int but Fails for T=std::string

Tags: c++, iterator, segmentation-fault, binary-tree

I have implemented a binary tree with an iterator in C++:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <memory>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
namespace binary_search_tree {

    template <typename T>
    struct binary_tree {
        std::unique_ptr<T> data_node;
        binary_tree<T>* parent = nullptr;
        std::unique_ptr<binary_tree<T>> left_node;
        std::unique_ptr<binary_tree<T>> right_node;


        std::unique_ptr<binary_tree<T>>& left() {
            if (left_node) {
                std::cout << "left: " << "\t";
                std::cout << left_node.get();
                return left_node;
            }
            return left_node;
            //throw std::logic_error("Left child is NULL");

        }

        std::unique_ptr<binary_tree<T>>& right() {
            std::cout << "\n Using right: " << "\t";
            if (right_node) {
                std::cout << "right: " << "\t";
                return right_node;
            }
            return right_node;

        }

        T data() {
            if (this) {
                if (this->data_node) {
                    return *this->data_node;
                }
            }
            //throw std::logic_error("Data is NULL");
        
        }

        void insert(T data) {
            if (!this->data_node) {
                this->data_node = std::make_unique<T>(data);

            }
            else {
                if (data > *this->data_node) {
                    if (!this->right_node) {
                        this->right_node = std::make_unique<binary_tree<T>>(this);
                    }
                    (*this->right_node).insert(data);

                }
                else {
                    if (!this->left_node) {
                        this->left_node = std::make_unique<binary_tree<T>>(this);
                    }
                    (*this->left_node).insert(data);

                }

            }

        }



        binary_tree<T>(T data) {
            this->insert(data);
            return;
        }

        binary_tree<T>() {
            return;
        }

        binary_tree<T>(binary_tree<T>* parent_ptr) {
            this->parent = parent_ptr;
            return;
        }

        struct iterator {
            binary_tree<T>* current;
            binary_tree<T>* root;
            binary_tree<T>* end;


            bool operator==(iterator other) const {
                return current == other.current;
            }
            bool operator!=(iterator other) const {
                return current != other.current;
            }

            void operator++() {
                //check if current is valid
                if (!current) {
                    return;
                }
                //if current reaches last leafe 
                if (current == root->findEndRightLeaf(this->root)) {
                    current = nullptr;
                    return;
                }

                if (current && current->right_node) {
                    // Move to the leftmost leaf of the right subtree
                    current = current->findStartLeftLeaf(current->right_node.get());
                }
                else if (current && current->parent && current == current->parent->left_node.get()) {
                    // Move up to the parent if it's the left child
                    current = current->parent;
                }
                else {
                    // Move upward until a left child is encountered or reach the end
                    while (current && current->parent && current == current->parent->right_node.get()) {
                        current = current->parent;
                    }
                    if (current && current->parent) {
                        // Move to the parent if it's a left child
                        current = current->parent;
                    }
                }
            }
            const T& operator*() {
                if (current) {
                    return current->data();
                }
                else {
                    // Handle the case when trying to dereference the end iterator
                    throw std::out_of_range("Dereferencing in iterator is not valid");
                }
            }
            iterator() {
                ;
            }
            iterator(binary_tree<T>* tree_pointer) : current(tree_pointer), root(tree_pointer), end(nullptr) {
                if (tree_pointer) {
                    this->root = tree_pointer->findRoot(tree_pointer);
                }
                else {
                    this->root = tree_pointer;
                }
            }
            iterator(const iterator& tree_iterator) : current(tree_iterator.current), root(tree_iterator.current), end(nullptr) {
                if (tree_iterator.current) {
                    this->root = this->current->findRoot(this->current);
                }
                else {
                    this->root = tree_iterator.current;
                }
            
            }
        };

        const iterator begin() {
            if (this) {
                binary_tree<T>* leftmostLeaf = findStartLeftLeaf(this);
                return iterator(leftmostLeaf);
            }

        }
        const iterator end() {
            return iterator(nullptr);
        }

        binary_tree<T>* findStartLeftLeaf(binary_tree<T>* node) {
            while (node && node->left_node) {
                node = node->left_node.get();
            }
            return node;
        }
        binary_tree<T>* findRoot(binary_tree<T>* node) {
        
            while (node && node->parent) {
                node = node->parent;
            }
            return node;
        }
        binary_tree<T>* findEndRightLeaf(binary_tree<T>* node) {
            while (node && node->right_node) {
                node = node->right_node.get();
            }
            return node;
        }
    };


}

using namespace binary_search_tree;



int main()
{
    //works with integers
    binary_tree<int> tree_int(2);
    tree_int.insert(3);
    tree_int.insert(1);
    tree_int.insert(7);
    tree_int.insert(0);
    tree_int.insert(1);
    tree_int.insert(1);

    std::cout << "Tree elements (int)  \n";
    for (const auto& value : tree_int) {
        std::cout << "value:\t" << value << "\n";
    }


    //fails with strings
    binary_tree<std::string> tree_str("hi");

    tree_str.insert("2");
    tree_str.insert("6");


    std::cout << "Tree elements (string) \n ";
    for (const auto& value : tree_str) {
        std::cout << "value:\t" << value << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

However, it appears to function correctly only when the template parameter (T) is set to int. When attempting to use std::string as the template parameter, the iterator does not work and I get a segmention fault error. I do not know why. I hope somebody can point the mistake out and/or provide a solution with explanation.

Comment: This gives several warnings that you might want to investigate first.

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run this program, where did your debugger show you to be the location of the crash, and what was the reason for it?

Comment: `if (this)` ? ?

Comment: Traditionally BSTs reject duplicate keys.

Comment: @Kenny is right: fix the warnings and you'll fix your bug

Comment: *I have implemented a binary tree with an iterator in C++* -- Off topic, but how exactly do you iterate a binary tree?  There are at least 4 major ways -- pre-order, in-order, post-order, level-order.  Your iterator only does one of these ways, as far as I can see.

Comment: Does your btree<std::string> have correct ordering (before using the iterators)?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Don't post working code. Post non-working code. If you have a problem with `binary_tree<string>`, post code that has `binary_tree<string>` in it.

Comment: Aside, your iteration is comically inefficient, calling findEndRightLeaf Every. Single. Time. In fact this function is not needed at all. If the node has a right child, go right and then go left until the end. Otherwise if the node is a left child, go up. Otherwise go up until you either see the root (then the iteration ends) or see a node that is a left child (and then go up once more).

Answer (score 4):

I see multiple areas of *undefined behavior* in your code:

- `this` can **never** legally be `nullptr` (and compilers can optimize based on that assumption), so *never* use `if (this)`. Calling a method on a `nullptr` object pointer is always *UB*.
- Your `data()` method doesn't `return` anything at all if `data_node` is `nullptr`, thus leaving the return value *indeterminate*, which is *UB*. For `std::string`, that means you are returning an invalid object.
- `data()` returns **by value**, but your iterator's `operator*` returns the `data()` value **by (const) reference**. The `data()` value goes out of scope upon the operator's exit (thus destroying a `std::string` object), leaving the iterator's returned reference *dangling*, which is *UB*.

Comment: Thanks for the great help and explanations.